# How is this expression related to arithmetic/geometric mean?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

From the [Wikipedia page on Hoeffding's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma), the page states

$$
L''(h)= -\frac{ab e^h}{(b-a e^h)^2}
$$

From the arithmetic, geometric mean inequality we thus see that $L''(h)\le\frac14$ for all $h$, and thus, from Taylor's theorem, there is some $0 \le \theta \le 1$ such that

$$L(h) = L(0) + h L'(0) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 L''(h\theta) \leq \frac{1}{8}h^2$$

**Questions**

1. How is the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality derived? It is not obvious to me how to relate $L^{\prime\prime}(h)$ to this.
2. For Taylor's theorem, why does it say "for some $\theta$," shouldn't this be true for all $\theta$ since $L^{\prime\prime}(h) < \frac14$ for all $h$?

Comment: Rewrite it as $(-a)be^h \le \frac 14 (b+(-a)e^h)^2$. Can you see AM-GM now? Note that $a \le 0 \le b$.

Comment: Oh yes, very tricky because $-\sqrt{(-a)be^h} \leq \frac{1}{2}b + (-a)e^h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context is $a \le 0 \le b$, and
$$
 \sqrt{-ab e^h} = \sqrt{b (-ae^h)} \le \frac 12 \bigl(b + (-ae^h) \bigr)
$$
gives the desired estimate $L''(h) \le 1/4$.

Taylor's theorem states that
$$
L(h) = L(0) + h L'(0) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 L''(h\theta) 
$$
for some $\theta \in (0, 1)$.

As you correctly said, $L''(h\theta) \le 1/4$ holds for all those $\theta$. It follows (together with $L(0) = L'(0) = 0$) that $L(h) \le h^2/8$. This final estimate does not involve $\theta$ anymore.

Comment: maybe I went over this too fast. I actually don't understand the Taylor part, shouldn't that be an approximation instead of an inequality since it is truncated at the second derivative? or is there some part of Taylors theorem which says that is exact?

Comment: @Joff: It is Taylor's theorem with the Lagrange remainder, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder. Sometimes it is written as $L(h) = L(0) + h L'(0) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 L''(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $h$.